# Look back and reference a specific series of historical values efficiently in large data frame

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset where I need to look back 24h, 48h, 56h ,etc. hours and generate a mean value.

This is an example of working code showing exactly the output I want:

```
library(tidyverse)

#dummy data
datetime <- seq(ymd_hms("2023-07-01 00:00:00"),ymd_hms("2023-07-10 00:00:00"), "1 hour")
value <- runif(length(datetime), 0, 1)
df <- tibble(datetime, value)

#define historic values required and calculate mean historic value
sequence <- days(1:5)
out <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  row <- df$datetime[i]
  final_sequence <- row - sequence
  value <- 
    df %>% 
    filter(datetime %in% final_sequence) %>%
    select(datetime, value) %>% 
    summarise(mean_historic_value = mean(value),
              sd_historic_value = sd(value))
  out[[i]] <- value
  print(i)
}

out <- bind_rows(out)
bind_cols(df, out)
```

While this works, it is dreadfully slow and I have multiple 100,000 row datasets to deal with.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I know I can use `purrr` and multicore, but prefer not to.

Comment: I think the [`slider` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slider/vignettes/slider.html) is what you're looking for, specifically the `slide_period` functionality. That should be user-friendly and much faster than what you've got. If you really want speed, the `RcppRoll` package will offer much more capability and fantastic speed.

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is regularly spaced, just use the `dplyr ::lag()` function to collect the previous values.

The laggedvalues variables is a data frame where each column are the values from the previous periods.  Then is it a simple matter of summarizing the data by row.

```
#dummy data
library(lubridate)
datetime <- seq(ymd_hms("2023-07-01 00:00:00"),ymd_hms("2023-07-10 00:00:00"), "1 hour")
value <- runif(length(datetime), 0, 1)
df <- tibble(datetime, value)

libary(dplyr)
laggedValues <- cbind(df$value, lag(df$value, 24), lag(df$value, 48), lag(df$value, 72), lag(df$value, 96), lag(df$value, 120))
means <- rowMeans(laggedValues, na.rm=TRUE)
stddevs <- apply(laggedValues, 1, function(x){
   sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)
})

answer<- data.frame(df$datetime, means, stddevs)
answer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime <- seq(ymd_hms("2010-07-01 00:00:00"),ymd_hms("2023-07-10 00:00:00"), "1 hour")
value <- runif(length(datetime), 0, 1)
df <- tibble(datetime, value)
df

library(tidyverse); 
df |>
  mutate(avg24 = slider::slide_index_dbl(value, datetime, mean, .before = hours(24)),
         avg48 = slider::slide_index_dbl(value, datetime, mean, .before = hours(48)),
         avg56 = slider::slide_index_dbl(value, datetime, mean, .before = hours(56)))
```

This takes just over a second for 100k rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using **`data.table`**'s `frollmean` assuming you have a complete series without missing hours.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

ranges <- c(24, 48, 56)

df[, (paste("avg", ranges)) := frollmean(value, ranges)]
```